# To get table details

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to get all table names and fields in that table from a particular database.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: SELECT t.name AS table_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
ORDER BY table_name;

Comment: And why doesn't that answer your needs? What else do you need to do?

Comment: You might want to look at `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` then.

Comment: ok. thank you Mr.Martin Smith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at the `sys.objects` and `sys.columns` tables:

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.OBJECTS
WHERE TYPE = 'U'
```

Would give you all of the tables in that database (Type U)

```
SELECT 'Table name : ' +  so.name, ' Column Name: ' + sc.name FROM SYS.OBJECTS so
INNER JOIN sys.columns sc ON sc.OBJECT_ID = so.OBJECT_ID
WHERE TYPE = 'U'
```

Would give you all of the tables in that database and the column names.  You could filter on these queries and do `WHERE so.name = 'Your Table'`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx

Answer (score 2):

use the syntax :-sp_help your table name

like this

**sp_help Payroll_Shift**

[image]